# pandas column with a dictionary to match another column with those dictionary valuess

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have one dataframe df as:

```
invoice_id|customer_id|items|batch

110|425|{'a': 50, 'b': 46}|no518

994528|a863|{'a': 21, 'c': 25}|as22

24|t311|{'scissor': 6, 'rock': 6}|af10
```

and another dataframe df1 as :

```
invoice_id|defect

110|a

994528|c
```

i want to search the value in df1['defect'] in df['items'] column.
This is my expected output:

```
invoice_id|customer_id|items|batch|defects_in_items

110|425|{'a': 50, 'b': 46}|no518|50

994528|a863|{'a': 21, 'c': 25}|as22|25

24|t311|{'scissor': 6, 'rock': 6}|af10|0
```

Can anybody help. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you should first have a look  on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge the two dataframe, and then use apply.

```
import ast
df2 = df.merge(df1, on=["invoice_id"], how="left")
df2["defects_in_items"] = df2.apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x["items"]).get(x["defect"],0), axis=1)
df2.iloc[:,[0,1,2,3,5]]
```

result:

```
    invoice_id  customer_id items                      batch    defects_in_items
0   110         425         {'a': 50, 'b': 46}         no518    50
1   994528      a863        {'a': 21, 'c': 25}         as22     25
2   24          t311        {'scissor': 6, 'rock': 6}  af10     0
```

ps. I use a txt file to get the two dataframe, so my 'items' column's type is str, ast.literal_eval is to change the column's type to dict.

Answer (score 1):

First, create a mapping using `map`:

```
mapping = df.invoice_id.map(df1.set_index('invoice_id').defect)

mapping
0      a
1      c
2    NaN
Name: invoice_id, dtype: object
```

Next, iterate over `df['items']` and index with the appropriate `mapping` value for that row:

```
df['defects_in_items'] = [i.get(j, 0) for i, j in zip(df['items'], mapping)]
```

Or, equivalently, define a function to perform the mapping and `vectorize` it:

```
def mapper(i, j):
    return i.get(j, 0)

v = np.vectorize(mapper)
df['defects_in_items'] = v(df['items'], mapping)
```

Outputs this;

```
df

   invoice_id customer_id                      items  batch  defects_in_items
0         110         425         {'a': 50, 'b': 46}  no518                50
1      994528        a863         {'a': 21, 'c': 25}   as22                25
2          24        t311  {'scissor': 6, 'rock': 6}   af10                 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
# create sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'invoice_id':[110,994528,24],
                   'customer_id':['425','a863','t311'],
                   'citems' :[{'a': 50, 'b': 46},{'a': 21, 'c': 25},{'scissor': 6, 'rock': 6}],
                  'batch':['no518','as22','af10']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'invoice_id':[110,994528], 'defect':['a','c']})

## merge data
df = df.merge(df2, on='invoice_id', how='left').fillna(0)

## iterate over rows and create new column
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['defect'] in row['citems']:
        df.loc[index, 'defect_in_items'] = df.loc[index, 'citems'].get(df.loc[index, 'defect'],0)
    else:
        df.loc[index, 'defect_in_items'] = 0

## answer

    batch         citems               customer_id  invoice_id  defect  defect_in_items
0   no518   {'a': 50, 'b': 46}            425.          110         a       50.0
1   as22    {'a': 21, 'c': 25}            a863        994528        c       25.0
2   af10    {'scissor': 6, 'rock': 6}     t311          24          0       0.0
```